# React - call two methods, but only last method logout is called

Tags: reactjs, methods

I am calling this message after success, I want to call success message first and then logout. But currently, only logout is called and it signed out.

```
 const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);

  const message = useCallback(
    () => {
      msg('successfully');
      logout();
    },
    [success, logout],
  );

return (
    <>
      {success && message()}
```

Comment: is it possible that `success` is an async process? could you share the code for the respective functions as well?

Comment: I have edited the code